# How can rustfmt be configured to not emit aligning spaces for the match unsafe block pattern?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

My `rustfmt` config currently formats the following code to have aligning spaces as is shown bellow. I have replaced spaces with `.` and tabs with `--->` in the following code.

```
fn main() {
--->match unsafe {
--->--->......0 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
--->--->.....} {
--->--->0 => println!("0"),
--->--->_ => println!("not 0 or 1"),
--->}
}
```

My `rustfmt` config(`rustfmt.toml` file) that produced the above code example:

```
tab_spaces = 4
hard_tabs = true
array_layout = "Block"
reorder_imports = true
newline_style = "Unix"
spaces_within_angle_brackets = false
spaces_within_parens = false
spaces_within_square_brackets = false
fn_args_layout = "Block"
fn_call_style = "Block"
fn_return_indent = "WithArgs"
fn_brace_style = "SameLineWhere"
generics_indent= "Block"
item_brace_style = "PreferSameLine"
control_style = "Rfc"
match_style = "Rfc"
unsafe_style = "Rfc"
where_layout = "Horizontal"
where_pred_indent = "Block"
where_style = "Rfc"
```

How can `rustfmt` be configured to not emit the aligning spaces(marked by: `.`) for the prior code, so `rustfmt` only indents with tabs like the following code?

```
fn main() {
--->match unsafe {
--->--->0 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
--->--->} {
--->--->0 => println!("0"),
--->--->_ => println!("not 0 or 1"),
--->}
}
```

Comment: How do I update rustfmt? I am getting Unknown configuration option `fn_brace_style` (which is in your post above)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug. I created a [PR](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustfmt/pull/1633) to fix this, so after it gets merged rustfmt will not emit spaces with your configuration.